# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??=' Discord.JS Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

When I deploy my Branch I get this error in logs

[Here is the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hwoG.png)

Anyone can help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Nullish assignment is first supported in Node 15. It sounds like whatever version of Node your app is using is not to that point yet.

[Specify a more recent Node version for Heroku to run](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support) in your package:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
```

otherwise it uses 14 by default (which is a slightly older LTS version which does not support this relatively new syntax).

Comment: Thanks this fixed it but now I get this error https://prnt.sc/26co4k3

Comment: Your link is requiring me to complete some sort of security check and not showing anything. As always, please specify details in text, not in images